# the best method for encryption data

Tags: encryption, cryptography, xor

We have 1 Mega byte size data.

What kind of method is the best security for encryption?

1. XOR the data with the same size key (random 1Mb key).
2. Use Symmetric-key cryptography like AES 256 (use 256 bit size key)

The key point of question is, In case we can use the same size of key for the data, what method is the best for encryption.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) barely qualifies as encryption at all. There's no reason to avoid (2) here.

Comment: (1) is the benchmark for encryption, at least in terms of Shannon's Perfect Secrecy. You literally can't get more secure than the one-time pad. However, as I say below it's not very useful in real life.

Comment: @EJP First qualifies as an ultimate encryption actually being a one-time pad.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about crypto in general, not about programming specificially.

Comment: Personally I don't think you can recommend any cryptographic algorithm without a specific use case. You could go for AES-GCM mode encryption (with a good IV, IV included in additional authenticated data of GCM) if you require a very generic and safe method of encrypting data. Key size may not matter as much as you would expect if you don't know how to apply AES or cryptography/security in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" depends on what you require. For one-time encryption where, let's say, you have the key securely stored in some safe place where 
a) you can't lose it 
b) others can't get at it

and maybe we should add 
c) if it's lost for good, that's not going to cause any harm that you can't live with

or at least
d) you'd much rather lose the data forever than let anyone else ever get hold of it

In that case, a one-time pad, assuming it's truly random, is the only way to ensure that no decryption can ever work. So that's pretty secure.

For most practical purposes, though, it's no good at all. For example, for continued use in communication, you need to be able to securely transmit messages of 1MB in length for each 1MB you want to encrypt. Of you can do that, you might as well transmit your messages on this same presumptively secure channel. For practical security, using some tested open implementation of a known and so far reliable cryptographic primitive is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. You enlighten me.

Comment: Some interesting points in that article, but still his method is severely limited in its applications. For example, it's only usable if you happen to know in advance of need that you're going to require secure communication with a particular person, and you take the trouble to prepare for it. It can't be generalized, since it requires a direct physical contact with each communicant. It's incredibly bulky - you have to maintain a reservoir of randomness for each correspondent, and track its level. So much more, so little space. Take Dan Boneh's crypto course, you'll like it.